Не удается инициализировать Kubernetes в Ubuntu 22.04
Выполняю установку на чистую виртуальную машину с Ubuntu 22.04, для виртуализации использую Proxmox.
Создал Master и Worker в одном VLAN, адреса они также получают из одной подсети. При попытке инициализировать Kubernetes на master сервере выдаёт ошибку по истечении 4-х минут:
"[kubelet-check] Waiting for a healthy kubelet at http://127.0.0.1:10248/healthz. This can take up to 4m0s"

Также не даёт посмотреть ноды при помощи команды kubectl get nodes, выдаёт "connection refused". Код от начала и до момента, когда возникает ошибка, представлен ниже:
# install packages
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.30/deb/Release.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg
echo 'deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg] https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.30/deb/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl containerd
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
# activate specific modules
# overlay — The overlay module provides overlay filesystem support, which Kubernetes uses for its pod network abstraction
# br_netfilter — This module enables bridge netfilter support in the Linux kernel, which is required for Kubernetes networking and policy.
sudo -i
modprobe br_netfilter
modprobe overlay
# enable packet forwarding, enable packets crossing a bridge are sent to iptables for processing
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
# return to user
# In v1.22 and later, if the user does not set the cgroupDriver field under KubeletConfiguration, kubeadm defaults it to systemd.
# by default containerd set SystemdCgroup = false, so you need to activate SystemdCgroup = true, put it in /etc/containerd/config.toml
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/configure-cgroup-driver/
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#cgroup-drivers
sudo mkdir /etc/containerd/
sudo vim /etc/containerd/config.toml
version = 2
[plugins]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
   [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd]
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes]
        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc]
          runtime_type = "io.containerd.runc.v2"
          [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc.options]
            SystemdCgroup = true
sudo systemctl restart containerd            
# get master ip for --apiserver-advertise-address
ip a
# to access kubernetes from external network you need to additionaly set flag with external ip --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=158.160.111.211
sudo kubeadm init \
  --apiserver-advertise-address=10.128.0.28 \
  --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16


UPD: Нашел ошибку самостоятельно, проблема была во включенном swap. Для решения потребовалось ввести команду swapoff -a, после проверить что он действительно отключился через free и прописать его постоянное отключение до следующего включения вручную при помощи команды sudo sed -i '/ swap / s/^/#/' /etc/fstab. В конечном итоге, кластер развернулся. Все ноды и поды встали в state READY.
